# The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. Androidx

Tags: java, android, androidx

i created a dialog box and i press it for the first time it shows my dialog box correctly, but when i close it with phone's back button and press it again, the dialog does not appear and the app crash. Why is my code not working?
I got the error mentioned in the title.

There is my code:

```
   final AlertDialog.Builder raspunsgresit = new AlertDialog.Builder(Intrebarea341.this);
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(Intrebarea341.this);
    final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.raspuns341, null);
    raspunsgresit.setView(view);
    raspunsgresit.setPositiveButton("", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

And there i show it:

```
   btnIncrement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //RASPUNS CORECT
            if (!i1.isChecked() && i2.isChecked() && !i3.isChecked()) {
                raspunscorect.show();
            } else if (i1.isChecked() && i2.isChecked()) {
                raspunsgresit.show();
            } else if (i1.isChecked() && i3.isChecked()) {
                raspunsgresit.show();
            } else if (i2.isChecked() && i3.isChecked()) {
                raspunsgresit.show();
            } else if (i1.isChecked() && i2.isChecked() && i3.isChecked()) {
                raspunsgresit.show();
            } else if (i1.isChecked()) {
                raspunsgresit.show();
            } else if (i2.isChecked()) {
                raspunsgresit.show();
            } else if (i3.isChecked()) {
                raspunsgresit.show();
            }


        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you share your activity code?

Comment: try using

raspunsgresit.dismiss();
before

finish();

Comment: it's dlg.dismiss();  but it doesn't work..

Comment: can someone help me?